# C++11 string assignment operator

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream text("text.txt");

istreambuf_iterator<char> iis(text);
string longest_phrase, _longest;

while (iis != istreambuf_iterator<char>()) {
    if ( *iis != '.' ) {
        _longest.push_back(*iis);
        ++iis;
        continue;
    }
    if ( _longest.size() > longest_phrase.size() )
        longest_phrase = move(_longest); //I want to move the data of _longest to longest_phrase. Just move! Not to copy!
    cout << _longest.empty(); //why _longest is not empty??
            //_longest.clear();
    ++iis;
}
text.close();
longest_phrase.push_back('.');
cout << "longest phrase is " << longest_phrase;
return 0;
}
```

This code searches for the longest phrase in file. 
So why the conversion from lvalue to rvalue doesnt work?

Edit:
That's why I thought that it did not work:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(vector<int> &&v): vec( move(v) ) {}
    vector<int> vec;
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> ints(50, 44);
    Vector obj( move(ints) );
    cout << ints.empty();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all for the quick and helpful answers!

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't work?

Comment: _longest.empty(); was returning false.
But now I know that move assignment operator of string implemented by swapping two strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not make concrete assumptions on the state of a moved-from object of the standard library, other than the fact that it is a legal state (unless further post-conditions of the move-assignment operator or move constructor are specified).

Per paragraph 17.6.5.15 of the C++11 Standard:

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may
>   be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be
>   placed in a valid but unspecified state.

Moreover, paragraphs 21.4.2/21-23 about the move-assignment operator of the `basic_string` class template do not specify anything about whether the moved-from string shall be left in a state such that invoking `empty()` on it returns `true`.

Calling `empty()` is legal in this case, since it does not have any pre-conditions on the state of the `string` object it is invoked on; on the other hand, you cannot make assumptions on what its return value shall be.

Comment: I thought that after the move of the object it always becomes empty. But as I see it depends on implementation. Anyway, thank you! 
And take a look at an example with the move of vector (above)

Comment: @Yivo: Right, it does depend on the implementation. Btw, if this answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted (or any other answer posted by other users that you may prefer).

Comment: @Yivo as a concrete practical example, a `std::string` that uses the "small-string optimization" could do less effort when moved from by leaving its contents intact (not sure if that is legal under the standard, is small string optimization allowed?).  Or a container could `swap` on `move` and leave the destruction of the elements in the moved-to container to the destruction of the moved-from container (also, may not be legal under the standard, depending on how it specifies contained-object lifetimes).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have pointed out that by the standard you cannot rely on a move operation from a string object leaving that object empty.

However, you should expect that something more efficient than a copy is taking place.  What is certainly happening is that your compiler's `basic_string<>& operator=(basic_string<>&&)` (the string 'move assignment') is implemented by swapping the two string objects (which is exactly what the standard sort of suggests: "Note: A
valid implementation is swap(str).").

g++ apparently implements the string move assignment this way.

So you don't need to worry about efficiency - there should be no unnecessary copying of the string going on.  However, you do need to make sure that the moved from string is cleared after the move, if you're going to use that object anymore.

Comment: I did not know that string move assignment operator implemented by this way.
`string str1 = "text1";`
`string str2 = "text2";`
`str1 = move(str2);`
and now str1 is text2 and str2 is text1.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what the others said about moving and using the moved object after that, a move is not exactly what you want to do here. What you *conceptually* want to is assign the content of `_longest` to `longest_phrase` and clear `_longest`. You were right in trying to avoid copying and reallocation, but you can achieve that easily by swapping:

```
 if ( _longest.size() > longest_phrase.size() )
 {
    longest_phrase.clear(); // don't need the old content any more
    longest_phrase.swap(_longest); //move the data of _longest to longest_phrase
 }
 assert(_longest.empty());
```

Comment: Why not move _longest to longest_phrase and then clear() _longest? That is more explicit about the intent.

Comment: Is `longest_phrase.swap(_longest);` equivalent to `longest_phrase = move(_longest);` ?

Comment: @Yivo: no, it's not. It does the thig you want (moving the content and leaving `_longest` in a defined state), while `move(_longest)` does not.

Comment: @SebastianRedl there are much ways to improve that, e.g. define `_longest` inside the loop, to get the content reset implicitly at the end of each loop.

Comment: @ArneMertz: `longest_phrase.clear(); longest_phrase.swap(_longest);` is semantically pretty much equivalent to `longest_phrase = move(_longest); _longest.clear();`. Some differences in retaining storage. I just think using the move is clearer about the intent.